# Different Date Formats in Source XML

Tags: xml, datetime, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm using XSLT 2.0 to transform dates from MM/dd/yyyy to yyyy-MM-dd. It seemed simple enough until I realized that my source dropped all leading zeros. so sometimmes my input is

```
<col11>11/14/2014</col11>
```

but sometimes it looks like this

```
<col11>1/5/2015</col15>
```

So I'm using this to format it,

```
   <outputcolumn>
   <xsl:variable name="date1" select="col11"/>
   <xsl:variable name="formatted_date1" select="concat(substring($date1,7,4),'-',substring($date1,1,2),'-',substring($date1,4,2))"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$formatted_date1"/>
    </outputcolumn>
```

That works great for the first input, but not the second one which drops the leading zeros.

How do you format dates where leading zeros have been dropped resulting in different formats?

Answer (score 2):

You could `tokenize()` and `format-number()`...

```
<xsl:template match="col11">
  <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(normalize-space(),'/')"/>
  <outputcolumn>
    <xsl:value-of 
      select="($tokens[3],
      format-number(number($tokens[1]),'00'),
      format-number(number($tokens[2]),'00'))" 
      separator="-"/>
  </outputcolumn>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to @Daniel Haley 's solution [credits goes to him]:

create a valid date for schematype "xs:date()" [format: YYYY-MM-dd]:

```
<xsl:variable name="dateparts" select="tokenize(normalize-space(),'/')"/>
<xsl:variable name="validdate" select="concat($dateparts[3], '-', format-number(number($dateparts[1]), '00'), '-', format-number(number($dateparts[2]), '00'))"/>
```

**Function** `format-date` [w3#function-format-date](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-format-date):

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-date(xs:date($validdate), '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')"/>
```

**Hint** namespace-prefix `xs` must be defined as `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`

Comment: Your date is already in the YYYY-MM-DD format, so formatting it using `format-date()` accomplishes nothing.

Comment: in case of YYYY-MM-DD that's true. for every other possible output-format it's a way to go.

Comment: For every other possible output format, you can assemble the tokens in the right format to begin with, without going through YYYY-MM-DD.